# Cannot host WebSocket Server - error during handshake

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, websocket, http-status-code-404

I want to try a WebSockets and I found this artcile on the internet [Using WebSocket in .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/618032/using-websocket-in-net-part)
I am sure that I did every step properly, I enabled WebSockets in IIS, I wrote all clases which are mention in article, I register HTTP Handler in web.config etc.. but when I want to try it I still get exception:

*WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/CodeProjectWeb/WSHandler.ashx' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404*

I know that 404 probably means that URL is wrong, but how can be wrong? Some additional info: I am running on windows 10, IIS 10.0 Express, .NET 4.6, Visual Studio 2013, I tried it on Google Chrome, Firefox (both last versions).
To be honest, this is not first tutorial which I tried. I already tried antoher 3-4 articles about WebSocket in .NET, also I tried use SignalR but still with the same results. I just dont know, I think that I am missing some important little thing..

If you need some more information just ask but I hope I write everything

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure it out (probably). I have to turn off Windows Firewall to make it work. So if you have similar problem just be sure that your Firewall is turn off.